# What and how causes a system to ignore DNS settings?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, centos, internal-dns

I have nameservers setup in the network config file and resolv file but the system is still using root dns to look up using root servers. Could having search in the resolv file send the look up to the windows domain controller and it use the root dns servers?

Comment: Exactly what is happening? Be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear but you should check the order in which the search is done:

```
[root@mgt1 ~]# grep ^hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```